# Oauth2 request token from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, request

I am testing my AWS Lambda nodejs locally via SAM, and I need to make an Oauth2 request to a third party API which I also have running locally.

I am trying to do this:

```
  request({
    url: 'http://localhost:4040/auth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
      user: 'xxx',
      pass: 'xxx'
    },
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
  }, function(err, res) {
      var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
      console.log("Access Token:", json.access_token);
    });
```

However, I am getting this info when invoking my function:

```
ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'body' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined","
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers?

Comment: In your `function(err, res){}` function, print `console.log(JSON.stringify(res)`, check the response's structure, I'm not sure that body is immediately available. Also, I suggest you rename your variable to `res_json`, it's very confusing to see a variable name `json`

Comment: `res` is undefined for some reason

Comment: There you go ... How about checking `err`?

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4040`.
My lambda is running on localhost:3000 and API on localhost:4040

Comment: So it seems like your `auth` server is refusing the request. What is this endpoint `localhost:4040/auth/token`, what's running?

Comment: My API is running in a docker container. I am able to request a token via postman and then use it to make other requests,

Comment: And your PostMan's request is identical to the one in the code snippet above? I know it sounds obvious, but it might be as simple as that

Comment: its identical, except in Postman I also have the `scope` of the access request as `read:org`

Comment: So maybe that's the issue? ... Can you try adding the scope to your code snippet?

Comment: apparently it wasn't the issue with my request but rather a bug in the version of the `aws-sam-cli` I was using. after downgrading, it works fine now.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2436

Comment: Superb, I'm glad to hear you sorted it out